# the same kind JVMTI EVENT processed by the same one thread?

Tags: java, jvm, jvmti

I register a `JVMTI Event` **MethodEntry** and its callback function is
`tdMethodEntry` and if there are many many **MethodEntry Events** and my question is that

> *these event will be processed by the same thread through queue? or be processed by several threads?*

Answer (score 1):

`MethodEntry` callbacks, like many other JVMTI event callbacks, are executed synchronously on the application thread that caused this event. If the application runs multiple threads, `MethodEntry` callbacks may run concurrently on these threads. Events are not queued.

See JVMTI spec [Events](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#EventSection) section.

Comment: if there are ***only one application thread*** but the callback does many things (consuming largely time). On this occasion, while ***only one thread***, there should be ***multiple threads*** run callback to executed synchronously on the application thread ?

Comment: @cainiaofei No, callbacks run on the same thread as the application code. From the application perspective the thread is stopped while a callback is in progress.

Comment: that is to say all **MethodEntry Event** processed by the same *one* thread? I am a little confuse, for through my program output I think it is processed by more than one thread.

Comment: @cainiaofei Yes, by the same one thread. What's wrong with the output?

Comment: In order to better describe my question, I place the code and the output description on github, [code and issue](https://github.com/cainiaofei/issueCommunicate]) the code is the file called **methodEntryCapturer** and output description called **issueDescription** .

Comment: @cainiaofei Yes, the output indicates you have multiple Java threads running. The assumption that there is only one application thread seems to be incorrect. BTW, MethodEntry callback receives `jthread` as one of parameters - you can check what thread exactly calls this event.

Comment: update the url of [code and issue](https://github.com/cainiaofei/issueCommunicate)